# Merge Laravel collections keys in only string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have this Laravel 5.3 tinny collection:

```
Collection {#325 ▼
  #items: array:8 [▼
    0 => 2638
    1 => 2100
    2 => 5407
    3 => 2970
    4 => 4481
    5 => 1611
    6 => 5345
    7 => 50
  ]
}
```

And I want combined in only string the values, I need this:

```
"2638,2100,5407,2970,4481,1611,5345,50"
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use implode https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-implode

if $collection is the value you have shown then

`dd($collection->implode(','));` should give the expected result

And if it's a multi-dimensional array, `implode` can also accept first arg as the key name:

```
$collection = collect([
  [ 'title' => 'Hello world' ],
  [ 'title' => 'Another Hello world' ]
]);

$collection->implode('title', ',')
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use PHP [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) or Laravel [`->implode()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-implode) method on collection:

```
implode(',', $collection->toArray());

$collection->implode(',');
```